# Ninja command not found in terminal

Tags: ios, macos, webrtc

-bash: ninja: command not found not found error in terminal. I am building webrtc for iOS and therefore I am following [WebRTC Guide](https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/) when I run below command in terminal it says `-bash: ninja: command not found`, am I missing anything? I have followed guide.

```
    ninja -C out_ios/Debug-iphoneos AppRTCDemo
    ninja -C out_ios/Release-iphoneos AppRTCDemo
    ninja -C out_sim/Debug-iphonesimulator AppRTCDemo
```

Comment: It's your `$PATH`.  Basic stuff for a user, let alone a developer.

Answer (score 2):

you are supposed to put the "depot_tools" root directory in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I met with a similar problem: I can use ninja without `sudo`, but it(ninja) can not be found when I add `sudo`.

I solved it by `cp path_to_ninja/ninja /usr/bin`